# c# for loop error in code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in c# and I am getting compilation error. Can anyone please help me?

**Update**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|OID.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
            //OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle");

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                //cmd.CommandText = "Select * from EMAILS WHERE EMAIL= '" + GlobalData.Email + "'";
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from EMAILS";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
               {

                   String email = row["email"].ToString();

                    if (email == GlobalData.Email)

                   {

                       Label2.Text = GlobalData.Email;
                       Label1.Text = GlobalData.Name;
                       Label3.Text = GlobalData.LastName;



                    }
                    else
                   {

                      Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

                    }



                }
        }
```

Now it is directly going to else section after the loop what will be error now

Comment: then what is the compilation error?

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1955: Non-invocable member 'System.Data.DataSet.Tables' cannot be used like a method. this is the error on run time

Comment: Looks like someone copied a VB code. Also, +1 for the `long I` in the for loop :)

Comment: On a side note, write for loops like: `for(int i = 0; i < table.Count; i++)`. Tighter and cleaner.

Comment: @HenkHolterman way too mainstream.

Comment: Actually i am Vb Developer and at a mean i have to write code in c# tahts why i am not actually understanding the exact syntax please help me more clearly

Comment: @Cicada - I think the OP needs a lot of stream to swim along.

Answer (score 5):

You're using `(` instead of `[`.

```
 for (I = 0; I <= ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows.Count - 1; I++)
 {
     String email = ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows[I].Item["email"];
```

Comment: Sir Error is now transferred to this line String email = ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows[I].Item["email"];

Comment: My cristal ball stopped working a while ago. If you don't provide more detail I can't really help you. What is the error? Also use *lady* instead of *sir* when referring to female entities, please!

Comment: O sorry I did'nt saw ur name exactly Miss Cicada.

Comment: @user1099825 - as with the main question, just saying "there is an error" isn't helping. We will always ask back: What error?

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this...

```
for (I = 0; I <= ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows.Count - 1; I++)
{
    String email = ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows[I]["email"].ToString();
    if (email == GlobalData.Email)
    {
        Label2.Text = GlobalData.Email;
        Label1.Text = GlobalData.Name;
        Label3.Text = GlobalData.LastName;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir this code dnt worked error is transferred to the next line

Comment: There is no Item Collection... If you want access to the email column the code should be String email = ds.Tables["Emails"].Rows[I]["email"].ToString();

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets instead of parentheses.

```
for (I = 0; I <= ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows.Count - 1; I++)
```

Tables is a parameter that returns a DataTableCollection, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are an vb developer, thats why you are using indexer as () instead of you should use []

```
for (I = 0; I <= ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows.Count - 1; I++)
```

and you will receiver error next lines

```
String email = ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows[I].Item["email"];
```

And... for the record you shouldn't directly prepare and call sql from codebehind.

I should edit my answer.

Foreach will make it much easier to use.

```
foreach (DataRow  row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //make sure that you have emil column in you datasource
    string email = row["email"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: @user1099825 string email = ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows[i]["email"]; try this

Comment: @user1099825 I must be int not long. Thats the error.

Comment: @user1099825  add ToString(), string email = ds.Tables["EMAILS"].Rows[i]["email"].ToString();

Comment: check your datasource probably EMAILS table is not exist in selected source...  ds.Table[0].Rows[I]["email"]... ?

Comment: Sir I am Sure of My Datasource which is names EMAILS

Comment: Dont use name of datasouce. try 0 ds.Table[0].Rows.Count... and use debugging to watch whats inside dataset.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can use foreach and make sure you have email column in your datasource.

Comment: Sir It Worked fine but it is now ignoring the conditions it Goes directly to else section after and respons.redirect to login page and not getting the DB values

Comment: Sir Check my UPdate in question

Comment: then this means there sth is wrong twith your data and if clause. debug it?

Comment: How Can I debug i have saved my entries correctly. I Also tried Oracle Db for this purpose but situation is same